# Insert a variable into a URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie here.

I would like to insert a value from JS variable into a URL part of an  tag.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var scrt_var = "xyz_nt"; 
</script
```

For example, take the above value and insert/replace in the below img src where it reads 'insert value here'.

```
 <TD>
   <img src="https://test.com/?target=alias(keepLastValue(aggregates.*.servera_*.abc-insert value here.errors)%2C%20'Errors')&preventCache=25308886"  height="250" width="620" />
 </TD>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: add onclick function to the element and pass the url to it. Combine url and js variable (in your JS code) to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an ID to your img and do something like:

```
<script>
    var scrt_var = "xyz_nt";
    var mylink = "http://your_url?your_var=" + scrt_var;
    document.getElementById('image').src = mylink;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *regex* `replace`

```
var scrt_var = "xyz_nt"; 
var image = document.querySelector("td img");
image.src = image.src.replace( /insert value here/, scrt_var );
```